# SwiftUI View Builder parameter cannot change state

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, viewbuilder

I am trying to create a SwiftUI view where I can pass a view builder. But by using a view builder parameter I cannot change the state. Is this due to the creation in the init method?
How can I achieve my expected behaviour?

```
struct Card_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @State
    static var bol: Bool = true
    static var previews: some View {
        Label(title: { content })
    }
    
    // Does not change the value
    private static var content: some View {
        Button(bol.description) {
            bol.toggle()
        }
    }
}


struct Label<Title>: View where Title: View {

    var body: some View {
        title
    }

    let title: Title
    public init(@ViewBuilder title: () -> Title) {
        self.title = title()
    }
}
```

If something is unclear pleas ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to `@ViewBuilder`, it's because `bol` is a `State` & not `Binding`. To solve this you need to bind the 2 properties like so:

```
struct Label<Title>: View where Title: View {

    @Binding
    var bol: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            title
            Button(bol.description) {
                // Changes the value
                bol.toggle()
                print(bol.description)
            }
        }
    }
    
    let title: Title
        
    
    public init(bol: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder title: () -> Title) {
        self.title = title()
        self._bol = bol
    }
}
```

And in `Card_Previews` replace `Label(title: { content })` with `Label(Bol: $bol, title: { content })`.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work either. :(

Comment: why is bol static in the preview?

Comment: yes. that was the problem. thank you so much. I was just so focused on the @State that I overlooked the static.

Comment: I don't know how we can now get a accepted answer or if I should just delete it.

Comment: It's Your call!